# Want to reduce the My SQL 5.7 run time on my query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Basically I want to find the next date when next message is execute for the customer. I run the query and get the desired output. However, MY SQL is taking more than 4 minutes for a large dataset.

```
 SELECT
     t1.cid, t1.requesttime,
    (SELECT t2.um_requesttime
     FROM db.table t2
     WHERE
        t2.um_CID = t1.um_CID AND
        t2.um_requesttime > t1.um_requesttime
    ORDER BY t2.um_requesttime
    LIMIT 1
   ) AS lead_date 
FROM db.table t1 order by
um_CID,um_requesttime
```

I tried this query but it gives me error on it.

```
SELECT
    t1.cid, t1.requesttime,
   (SELECT t2.um_requesttime 
    FROM db.table t2
    WHERE
        t2.um_CID = t1.um_CID AND
        t2.um_requesttime > t1.um_requesttime
    ORDER BY t2.um_requesttime LIMIT 1
   ) AS lead_date 
FROM db.table t1
USE INDEX for ORDER BY (t1.um_CID,t1.um_requesttime)
```

So if you could help me how we can optimize the time and make it more faster then it would be great.

Comment: `FROM db.table t1 um_CID,um_requesttime` -- Is the query well-formed? Aren't you missing an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: The query has no filering condition, so it return all the rows of the table. It's bound to be slow.

Comment: Please provide tables structure and sample data?  Does fileds `um_CID` and `um_requesttime` indexed? How match data have the table?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Data is more than 15 lac records.  And um_cid and um_requesttime is not indexed. So i was thinking to index them so that it could increase efficiency

Comment: I mean indexing will improve query performance. Add index and public performance change

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Can we index columns in this query. But how we can do t. I am trying to do but not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try whether the following query using JOIN  is a possible workaround?

```
SELECT
  t1.cid,
  t1.requesttime,
  MIN(t2.um_requesttime) AS lead_date
FROM
  db.table t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN db.table t2
  ON t2.um_CID = t1.um_CID AND t2.um_requesttime > t1.um_requesttime
GROUP BY
  t1.cid,
  t1.requesttime;
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean the right indexes should to increase the query performance:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
    ADD INDEX `um_CID_ix` (`um_CID`),
    ADD INDEX `um_requesttime_ix` (`um_requesttime`);
```

Here the fiddle [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=adc56055081526b1aca54890ef087bfe&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)